# Convolution of difference distribution doesn't conserve expectation - faulty assumption?

Tags: probability, signal-processing, convolution

I have observations of a system which I hypothesize is defined as $T = A + G$ where $T,A, G$ are random variables. I've measured the empirical continuous distributions $T$ and $A$, and the question is, what is the distribution of $G$?

Assuming $A$ and $G$ are independent, this is just the convolution integral for $T-G$, that is, since $i-(i-k)=k$,

$$
P_G(G=k)=\int_{i=0}^\infty P_T(T=i)P_A(A=i-k)
$$

Because the data for $T$ and $A$ are empirical distributions, I computed discrete PMFs with various discretizations and the following results don't depend much on what resolution to discretize.

Inputting my data, I get a nice distribution for $G$, however, there are two things I don't understand.

1. While the discrete PMFs that approximate $A$ and $T$ sum to 1, the sum of $P_G =.543$. Do I just renormalize?
2. $E[G]=.78$ while $E[T]=1.52$ and $E[A]=1.32$. Mean of $G$ is not affected by (1). I know even for correlated variables, $E[A+B]=E[A]+E[B]$, so something must be wrong. The only assumption I've made is that $A$ and $G$ are not correlated (so the convolution applies). Is this result telling me $A$ and $G$ are correlated? What can I do to find out if they are, given what I have? I cannot observe $G$ without $A$.

Edit: changed "Assuming $A$ and $G$ are not correlated" to "Assuming $A$ and $G$ are independent" per Dilip since the terminology used was incorrect.

Comment: Can you assume that $A$ and $G$ are (at least approximately) independent (not just uncorrelated)? If so, then you want to *deconvolve* $T$ and $A$ (not $G$), which is a different formula--but relatively straightforward. [The mistake here lies in assuming that $G=(A+G)-A$ can be computed with convolutions. To see why not, consider a case where $G$ is constantly $0$ but $A$ varies. Then $A+G=A$, but your formula for $A-A$ is really a formula for $A_1-A_2$ where the $A_i$ are independent and have the same distribution as $A$: their difference definitely is not zero.]

Comment: I can assume that $A$ and $G$ are independent but I'm not 100% sure they are. It seems like the appropriate first step is to assume independence. I think I see several of the flaws in my logic. So the problem becomes solving $T=G \ast A$ for $G$?

Comment: @whuber Tried a bunch of things to solve that. First attempt: ifft(fft(T)/fft(A)). Did not work. This is a well studied problem. Seems like the most effective approach is solving the problem $T=Ag$ where T is a vector, A is a matrix A(k,i) filled with the values A(k,i)=$P_A(k-i)$ from the sum convolution, and g is the unknown probability distribution vector. Tried solving this with truncated SVD. Result is ugly, namely lots of negative values. Pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement

> Assuming $A$ and $G$ are not correlated, this is just the convolution integral

is false. The distribution of the sum or difference of *independent*
random variables can be obtained via convolution-type formulas, but
this formula *does not hold* for uncorrelated random variables.

The key issue here is

> I've measured the empirical continuous distributions $T$ and $A$

whereas what you need is the (empirical) **joint** distribution of $T$ and $A$;
the individual (a.k.a. marginal) distributions do not suffice.

> The only assumption I've made is that A and G are not correlated (so the convolution applies). Is this result telling me A and G are correlated?

What the result is telling you is that $A$ and $G$ are *dependent* random variables. They *might* be correlated, and they *might not* be correlated;
it all depends on the joint distribution.  For example, if $(A,G)$
is uniformly distributed on the unit disc, then $A$ and $G$ are 
*uncorrelated but dependent* random variables.
Applying your convolution formula to the sum/difference of $A$ and $G$
in this case will *not* give you the distribution of $A\pm G$.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the fundamental differences between independence and correlation, I was definitely loose with my terminology.

Comment: As I stated above, I don't have access to the joint distribution of T and A. I may have, however, the values of predictors for both. Still, I'd like to estimate $G$ using the simplest model first before integrating over dependent variables. It seems to me my problem is more that I've assumed $T=G+A$ means $G=T-A$ (false), as @whuber points out.